# How to make the boundary of a 3D region smooth?

Tags: finite-element-method, regions, opencascade

I want to draw this region,but the surface is rough.I tried to find options to improve the surface but failed.

```
Region[RegionIntersection[Cylinder[{{0, 0, -2}, {0, 0, 2}}],
  Cylinder[{{0, -2, 0}, {0, 2, 0}}], 
  Cylinder[{{-2, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}]]]
```

which gives

[image]

besides, `PlotPoints -> 200` seems have no place to put.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sometimes, it is easier to discretize before intersecting.

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@RegionIntersection[
  Map[
   BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[#, 
     MaxCellMeasure -> (1 -> 0.05)] &, 
     {Cylinder[{{0, 0, -2}, {0, 0, 2}}], Cylinder[{{0, -2, 0}, {0, 2, 0}}], 
    Cylinder[{{-2, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}]}
   ]
  ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 17):

Using [OpenCascadeLink](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCascadeLink/tutorial/UsingOpenCascadeLink.html) from version 12.1 makes this easier and better quality:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
rr = RegionIntersection[Cylinder[{{0, 0, -2}, {0, 0, 2}}], 
   Cylinder[{{0, -2, 0}, {0, 2, 0}}], 
   Cylinder[{{-2, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}]];
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[rr, 
   "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> {"OpenCascade", 
     "ShapeSurfaceMeshOptions" -> {"LinearDeflection" -> 0.00125}}];
bmesh["Wireframe"[
  "MeshElementStyle" -> Directive[FaceForm[Green], EdgeForm[]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, that's great to know! I am eager to get my hand on the new version to try that!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, it's bit like with TetGenLink and TriangleLink, OCCL forms a low level interface and with time more high level functions will make use of that. OpenCascade is a huge library and this first version scratches the surface, I think. It will take time to exploit more of it.... It's hopefully  going to be easily accessible for you folks to make contributions too.

Comment: Please comment on which OpenCascade app is needed to make this work.

Comment: @murray, you just need Version 12.1 nothing else. ln the Documentation search for OpenCascadeLink for more information on this.

Comment: The name `OpenCascadeLink` suggests, as do things like `RLink`, a link to something external. What is that?

Comment: @murray, it's a link to [OpenCascade](https://www.opencascade.com/content/overview), does that help? The opencascade libraries now ship with mathematica 12.1 and the link, links to those shipped libraries.

Answer (score 14):

```
ri = RegionIntersection[Cylinder[{{0, 0, -2}, {0, 0, 2}}], 
   Cylinder[{{0, -2, 0}, {0, 2, 0}}], Cylinder[{{-2, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}]];
```

You can use `PlotPoints` as a suboption for `Method` options:

```
DiscretizeRegion[ri, 
 Method -> {"DualMarchingCubes", PlotPoints -> 150}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

In order to completeness,here we provide another ways to do this. Thanks
@xzczd suggestion。

Related [How to graph a solid common to multiple functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/267312/how-to-graph-a-solid-common-to-multiple-functions)

- **MeshFunctions**

```
Clear[f, g, h, fgh, ghf, hfg];
SetOptions[ContourPlot3D, PlotPoints -> 80, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
  Mesh -> {{0}, {0}, {0}}, BoundaryStyle -> None, Boxed -> False, 
  Axes -> False];
f = {x, y, z} |-> x^2 + y^2 - 1;
g = {x, y, z} |-> y^2 + z^2 - 1;
h = {x, y, z} |-> z^2 + x^2 - 1;
fgh = ContourPlot3D[
   f[x, y, z] == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {g, h}, 
   MeshShading -> {{Red, None}, {None, None}}, MeshStyle -> None];
ghf = ContourPlot3D[
   g[x, y, z] == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {h, f}, 
   MeshShading -> {{Yellow, None}, {None, None}}, MeshStyle -> None];
hfg = ContourPlot3D[
   h[x, y, z] == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {f, g}, 
   MeshShading -> {{Cyan, None}, {None, None}}, MeshStyle -> None];
Show[fgh, ghf, hfg]
```

[image]

- **CSGRegion**

```
CSGRegion["Intersection", {Cylinder[{{0, 0, -2}, {0, 0, 2}}], 
  Cylinder[{{0, -2, 0}, {0, 2, 0}}], 
  Cylinder[{{-2, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}]}, BaseStyle -> Darker@Cyan]
```

[image]

- **OpenCascadeLink`** (Thanks @user21)

```
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"];
shape = OpenCascadeShape[
   RegionIntersection[Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}], 
    Cylinder[{{0, -1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}], 
    Cylinder[{{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}]]];
bm = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[shape, 
    "ShapeSurfaceMeshOptions" -> {"AngularDeflection" -> .01}] // 
   BoundaryMeshRegion;
RegionPlot3D[bm, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Boxed -> False]
```

Or

```
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"];
reg1 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, -2}, {0, 0, 2}}];
reg2 = Cylinder[{{0, -2, 0}, {0, 2, 0}}];
reg3 = Cylinder[{{-2, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}];
shape1 = OpenCascadeShape[reg1];
shape2 = OpenCascadeShape[reg2];
shape3 = OpenCascadeShape[reg3];
bm = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[
    OpenCascadeShapeIntersection[shape1, shape2, shape3], 
    "ShapeSurfaceMeshOptions" -> {"AngularDeflection" -> .01}] // 
   BoundaryMeshRegion;
bm // Volume;
RegionPlot3D[bm, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Yet another way to discretize the [Steinmetz solid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinmetzSolid.html) is to directly derive the required inequalities using `RegionMember[]`:

```
ineq = Simplify[RegionMember[RegionIntersection[Cylinder[{{0, 0, -2}, {0, 0, 2}}], 
                                                Cylinder[{{0, -2, 0}, {0, 2, 0}}], 
                                                Cylinder[{{-2, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}]],
                             {x, y, z}], {x, y, z} ∈ Reals]
   -2 <= z <= 2 && x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && -2 <= y <= 2 && x^2 + z^2 <= 1 &&
   -2 <= x <= 2 && y^2 + z^2 <= 1
```

which can then be fed to `ImplicitRegion[]`:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[ineq, {x, y, z}];
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.02}]
```

[image: Steinmetz solid]

Answer (score 9):

```
reg = Polygon[
  Join[#, Reverse[#.DiagonalMatrix[{1, -1}]]] &@
   Table[{x, Min[AngleVector[Mod[x, Pi/2]]]}, {x, 0., 2 Pi, 2 Pi/(25*8)}]]

ParametricPlot3D[{{Cos[t], Sin[t], h}, {h, Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {Cos[t], h, Sin[t]}}, 
  Element[{t, h}, reg], ImageSize -> 600] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

For version 13.x, you need to use `` Visualization`Core`ParametricPlot3D `` instead of `ParametricPlot3D`.
Related link, [the-last-syntax-of-parametricplot3d-seems-broken-in-v13-x](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/277531/the-last-syntax-of-parametricplot3d-seems-broken-in-v13-x)

Answer (score 2):

Now I know how to solve this:

> besides, `PlotPoints -> 200` seems to have no place to put.

```
RegionIntersection[
    Cylinder[{{0, 0, -2}, {0, 0, 2}}],
    Cylinder[{{0, -2, 0}, {0, 2, 0}}], 
    Cylinder[{{-2, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}]] //
RegionPlot3D[#, PlotPoints->80]&
```

[image]