# Why can't this DiscretizeRegion display in full

Tags: regions

```
Plot3D[1.5 E^(-5.5 (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 5)^2), {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 2}, BoxRatios -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 25]

ℛ = ParametricRegion[{x, y, 1.5 E^(-5.5 (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 5)^2)},
                      {{x, -6, +6}, {y, -6, +6}}];
DiscretizeRegion[ℛ, AccuracyGoal -> 3]
```

The graphics processed by `DiscretizeRegion` are obviously incomplete.

Comment: try this ? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211178/how-to-make-the-surface-of-a-3d-region-smooth

Comment: I am puzzled. Usually, increasing the resolution with the option `MaxCellMeasure` helps, but here it seem as if `DiscretizeRegion` would not be able to compute a decent bounding box. Providing an eplicit bounding box with `DiscretizeRegion[\[ScriptCapitalR], {{-6, +6}, {-6, +6}, {-1, 2}}, 
 MaxCellMeasure -> (1 -> 0.01)]` helps, but then `MaxCellMeasure` option is entirely ignored. This is certainly a bug; please contact the support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the second argument to specify explicit bounds (as suggested by Henrik in comments) helps remove the empty regions:

```
DiscretizeRegion[ℛ, {{-6, 6}, {-6, 6}, {-1, 2}}, AccuracyGoal -> 3]
```

[image]

We can not use the option `PlotPoints` in  `DiscretizeRegion` directly. However, we can use the option `Method` and control mesh quality by injecting `PlotPoints` as a suboption for `"Discretization"`:

```
DiscretizeRegion[ℛ, {{-6, 6}, {-6, 6}, {-1, 2}},  
 AccuracyGoal -> 3, 
 Method -> {"Discretization" -> {"MarchingCubes", PlotPoints -> 100}, 
   "PostProcessing" -> {"SmoothMesh", "ImproveBoundaries"}}]
```

[image]

**Notes:**

If we remove the suboption `"PostProcessing" -> {"SmoothMesh", "ImproveBoundaries"}` we do get a similar picture but it takes longer:

```
DiscretizeRegion[ℛ, {{-6, 6}, {-6, 6}, {-1, 2}},  
 AccuracyGoal -> 3, 
 Method -> {"Discretization" -> {"MarchingCubes", PlotPoints -> 100}}]
```

[image]

If we remove the suboption `PlotPoints` we get

```
DiscretizeRegion[ℛ, {{-6, 6}, {-6, 6}, {-1, 2}},  
 AccuracyGoal -> 3, 
 Method -> {"Discretization" -> {"MarchingCubes"}, 
   "PostProcessing" -> {"SmoothMesh", "ImproveBoundaries"}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Monge patches](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MongePatch.html) like the one in the OP, when expressed as a `ParametricRegion[]`, are often troublesome to discretize without special treatment like what kglr does.

Instead, one could reformulate the surface as an `ImplicitRegion[]`, like so:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[z == 1.5 E^(-5.5 (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 5)^2),
                     {{x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}, {z, -1, 7}}];
```

tho you now have to specify a range for `z` as well.

With that,

```
DiscretizeRegion[reg, AccuracyGoal -> 3, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.15}]
```

[image: discretized Monge patch]