# The last syntax of `ParametricPlot3D` seems broken in V13.x

Tags: plotting, bugs, visualization, version-13.1, version-13.2

**Bug introduced in 13.0  and have been fixed in 13.2.1 .**

---

It seems not to work properly to use [`ParametricPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html) with parameters specified in a two-dimensional nonrectangular region.

Code and figure below are first found out by @cvgmt, where the plot generated by [`Plot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot3D.html) is the expected one.

```
{Plot3D[x*y, {x, y} ∈ Annulus[]], ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, x*y}, {x, y} ∈ Annulus[]]}
```

[image]

Comment: It is also broken in v13.1 on a Mac OS X x86

Comment: It works for v12.2.0 on Win7-x64 as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHPx9.png).

Comment: It is also broken in 13.2. Please report it to: support@wolfram.com

Answer (score 6):

Just as workaround till fixed

```
ClearAll["Global`"]
r = 1;
f[x_, y_] := (z = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]; If[z <= r/2 || z > r, Null, x*y]);
p1 = Plot3D[x*y, {x, y} ∈ Annulus[], ImageSize -> 300, PlotRange -> All];
p2 = ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, f[x, y]}, {x, y} ∈ Annulus[], 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotPoints -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
   ImageSize -> 300, PlotRange -> All];
Row[{p1, p2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Initially I tried this `f` but it did not work well

```
f[x_, y_] := If[Not[{x, y} ∈ Annulus[]], Null, x*y];
```

Because the above needed larger `MaxRecursion` and `PlotPoints` values to get similar plot, and this made the plot very slow.

**Update**

The slowness mentioned in the above comment was due to using `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"`, this below is much faster  and does not need large value of `MaxRecursion`

```
ClearAll["Global`"]
f[x_, y_] := If[Not[{x, y} ∈ Annulus[]], Null, x*y];
p1 = Plot3D[x*y, {x, y} ∈ Annulus[], ImageSize -> 300, PlotRange -> All];
p2 = ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, f[x, y]}, {x, y} ∈ Annulus[], 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", ImageSize -> 300, PlotPoints -> 20, 
   MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotRange -> All];
Row[{p1, p2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]