# ImplicitRegion in ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, bugs

In `13.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)`, if I write:

```
Show[ContourPlot[y == x^2/4, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, x}],
     ContourPlot[y == x^2/4, {x, 1, 2}, {y, 0, 2 - x}],
     AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image]

it's ok, but if I write:

```
ContourPlot[y == x^2/4, {x, y} ∈ ImplicitRegion[0 < x < 2 && y < x < 2 - y, {x, y}]]
```

I don't get any response. How can I fix? Thank you!

Comment: I can confirm that your code works in 12.3 and 13.0 (both Windows), but it doesn't work in 13.2 (Wolfram Cloud). It seems like a regression bug which should probably be reported to the technical support. Using ``SetSystemOptions["VisualizationOptions" -> {"Verbose" -> True}]`` also shows that some error occurs during plotting.

Comment: What [seems to be happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i4eL.png) is that ``RegionFunction`` gets set, but the ``RegionMemberFunction`` is not set up properly. However, even manually overriding ``RegionFunction`` unfortunately does not seem to work ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a bug,not only in 2D but also in 3D. [The last syntax of `ParametricPlot3D` seems broken in V13.x](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/277531/the-last-syntax-of-parametricplot3d-seems-broken-in-v13-x/277583#277583)

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[0 < x < 2 && y < x < 2 - y, {x, y}];
ContourPlot[
 y == x^2/4, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, {x, y} ∈ reg]]
```

[image]